# Running Selenium On Raspberry Pi: Possible GeckoDriver Issue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm fairly new to Pi's and Python and trying to run selenium to try to do a web automated program on my PI Model B. I have everything installed and just trying to run a simple command like:

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')

This should open FireFox (as I've installed IceWeasel) but I keep getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BingBotTest.py", line 3, in 
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 142, in **init**
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

I knew I needed the GeckoDriver for Firefox, so I downloaded it. I assumed I should download the ARM7 version of GeckoDriver. However when I extract it, it doesn't make an executable so I can route my code to it. Anyone with any guidance? Again I'm fairly new, so this could be a dumb question. Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using PhantomJS. Install phantomjs package, then you can use:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on your pi version processor for using geckodriver, which Pi version are you using, currently geckodrive are only prebuild for ARM7 (pi3B) , if you would like to run it on Zero or older pi you need to download the geckodriver code and made your own build for the ARM versions you need!

Answer (score 0):

Download geckodriver from below location and add it to your PATH veriable.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Exit existing command line and reopen the same. This should help you.